# Do all the precipitates undergo an equilibrium with its respective ions, why can't they dissociate fully?

Tags: equilibrium

I’m really confused about this. If we consider $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$, it can be seen it undergoes an equilibrium. But why it’s an equilibrium?

This is the equilibrium it undergoes $$\ce{Ca3(PO4)2_{(s)}<=> 3Ca^2+_{(aq)} + 2 PO4_{(aq)}^3-}$$

By the way I’m having a doubt of why some are using backward arrow for a dissociation of a particular precipitate while some are using a solid forward arrow for the same reaction. For an example let’s take $\ce{AgCl(s)}$

Now this is a place where a backward arrow is used,
$$\ce{AgCl_{(s)}<=> Ag+_{(aq)} + Cl_{(aq)}-}$$

But I have seen in some books where there is a solid forward arrow instead of back-ward arrow for the dissociation of $\ce{AgCl(s)}$.

Answer (score 1):

In the two examples you mentioned, we have an equilibrium between the solid and the small quantity of the solid that is soluble in water and completely dissociated:
$$\ce{Ca3(PO4)2_{(s)}<=> 3Ca^2+_{(aq)}  + 2 PO4^{3-}_{(aq)} }$$ 
$$\ce{AgCl_{(s)}<=> Ag^+(aq)_{(aq)}  + Cl^{-}_{(aq)} }$$

I think it's wrong to write a solid forward reaction.
It's an **heterogeneous equilibrium** between the solid state (the precipitate) and the aqueous state (ions constituents of the precipitate). The constant of this equilibrium is the solubility product $K_{\mathrm{sp}}$ of the precipitate.

Comment: @ Youmen Then if some one wrote  Ag+  +  Cl^-  --->(solid forward arrow)AgCl ,  is it correct? Could you explain it also?

Comment: @On the way to success Please see my answer (I have added  some explanations).

Comment: @ Youmen  How can you  say constant of Ag+(aq)+Cl−(aq)<---> (AgCl(s)  is the inverse of solubility product of  AgCl(s)<-->.Ag+(aq)+Cl−(aq)

Comment: @ On the way to success It's the definition of Ksp =[Ag+][Cl-]. Ok?

Comment: @ Youmen Yes I do know Ksp =[Ag+][Cl-] but I'm confused with about the thing you said " constant of Ag+(aq)+Cl−(aq)<---> (AgCl(s) is the inverse of solubility product of AgCl(s)<-->.Ag+(aq)+Cl−(aq)"

Comment: Because it's the reverse reaction.